# How does python know that dataclasses.field function is not a default value in a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Consider the following class:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
  a: int = 1
  b: int
```

Trying to execute this yields `TypeError: non-default argument 'b' follows default argument`

Now consider this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import config

@dataclass
class C:
  a: int = field(metadata=config(encoder=lambda x: x, decoder=lambda x: x))
  b: int
```

This executes without error.

The question is: how does the `field` function "cheat" the python interpreter and not considered a default value? Can I replicate this behavior in my own function?

Comment: the `field` function eventually outputs a `Field` object, there's no mention of `__init__` or `__post_init__` in the implementation. Is there some special handling of `field` in the python interpreter?

Comment: I understand the behavior of `field`, my question is how does it make python not complain about a default argument? does the interpreter have special handling for it as opposed to any other function/value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@dataclass` is not "interpreted by the interpreter", in the sense that the interpreter does not "know" it has to raise errors like `TypeError: non-default argument 'b' follows default argument`. Instead, `@dataclass` is a regular Python function that inspects the class object and [explicitly raises the error](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/dataclasses.py#L540-L541).

The high-level descriptions of this mechanism is that [`field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) returns a [`Field` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.Field) containing the meta-data passed to `field`. The `@dataclass` code [checks if class attribute values are `Field` objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/dataclasses.py#L726-L732), not whether they are created by `field` – one can write a custom function to construct a `Field` instance if needed.
Of course, the easiest approach is just to have a function that calls `field` in order to create a `Field`.

```
from dataclasses import field, MISSING


def auto_field(*, default=MISSING, default_factory=MISSING, init=True, metadata=None):
    """Field that inspects defaults to decide whether it is repr/hash'able"""
    if default is MISSING and default_factory is MISSING:
        return field(init=init, metadata=metadata)
    test_default = default if default is not MISSING else default_factory()
    return field(
        default=default, default_factory=default_factory, init=init, metadata=metadata,
        repr=type(test_default).__repr__ is not object.__repr__,
        hash=getattr(test_default, '__hash__', None) is not None,
        compare=getattr(test_default, '__hash__', None) is not None,
    )
```

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    a: int = auto_field()  # not counted as a default
    b: int
    c: list = auto_field(default_factory=list)


print(Foo(12, 42), hash(Foo(12, 42)))  # works because c is ignored for hashing
```

---

Note that conceptually, one is still restricted to the logic of `dataclass` and its `Field`s. For example, that means that one cannot create a "field which *has a default* but is not considered a default value" – depending on how one approaches it, `dataclass` would either ignore it or still raise an error when preparing the actual class.